# java argument for applet or java web start which is not listed in specification

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

jnlp file specification lists  some jvm arguments which can be applied to java-vm-args, my argument  is not in the list, I tried with the running with the argument  but it  was ignored , my jvm argument is  is

```
-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11,pkcs11
```

I tried adding it in my jnlp file to the attribute  java-vm-args ,

```
<j2se version="1.7+"  java-vm-args="-d32 -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11,pkcs11"/>
```

but this  argument was not applied to applet or java web start, Please advice can I add the above argument to  jvm in case of applets or java web start?

Answer (score 0):

Web Start has a limited set of parameters that can be passed on the command line.  Below is an excerpt from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)

> The property element defines a system property that will be available
>   through the System.getProperty and
>   System.setProperties methods. It has two required attributes: name and
>   value. For example:
>
> Properties set in the jnlp
>   file will normally be set by Java Web Start after the VM is started
>   but before the application is invoked. Some properties are considered
>   "secure" properties and can be passed as -Dkey=value arguments on the
>   java invocation command line.

```
The following properties are considered "secure" and will be passed to the VM in this way:  
- sun.java2d.noddraw
- javaws.cfg.jauthenticator   
- swing.useSystemFontSettings
- swing.metalTheme 
- http.agent  
- http.keepAlive
```

For an untrusted application, system properties set in the JNLP file will only be set by Java Web Start if they are considered secure, or if the property name begins with "jnlp." or "javaws.".

Comment: it means I cannot set this parameter?  what is the solution? we cannot write applet or java web start app  which needs parameters not listed in the specification?
is there any other means  of passing this parameter to jre , without this parameter  sunpkcs11 will not work  so obviously my app  will not work.

I tried adding it as  property, it   did not work, please give me  a wokaround.

Comment: It means that you need to use the `property` tag to pass along arguments that are NOT considered 'secure' by Web Start.

Comment: -Djava.security.debug property is  needed for sunpkcs, My code does nothing with that, I tried running a java class with main method by setting this property instead of passing jvm argument  I used System.setProperty("java.security.debug", "sunpkcs11,pkcs11"); it did not work also tried property tag in jnlp did not work.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400725/with-java-update-7-45-the-system-properties-no-more-set-from-jnlp-tag-property to see if this matches your problem.  We haven't signed our JNLP file but have another mechanism for passing in non-JVM parameters.