# JNLP insecure Properties

Tags: java, jnlp

I am having a problem with Java 8 and Signed JNLP files, I have built my jar file with the JNLP-INF/APPLICAION.JNLP Signed the jar and put a copy of the jnlp on my Web Site however I am still getting this error when running it.

Insecure property: (cmsport, 6880) specified in unsigned jnlp file will not be set.
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: jnlp.jar
Hello World how is it going 
cmsport: null

Comment: I think I have found the problem, it seems that Starting in Java 7 the Unsigned Certificates are not accepted when reading the JNLP Settings.

Comment: The above comment is wrong Unsigned Certificates should be ok. This is from the log and the jnlp was signed with the jar.                                                   
    
Insecure property: (cmsserver, u4-mysite.ca) specified in unsigned jnlp file will not be set.
Insecure property: (cmsport, 6880) specified in unsigned jnlp file will not be set.
security: Mark trusted: http://www.mysite.ca/Test.jnlp
basic: passing security checks; secureArgs:false, allSigned:false
basic: trusted app: true, -secure=false
basic: JREMatcher:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [With Java 7 Update 45, the System Properties no Longer Set from JNLP Tag "Property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400725/with-java-7-update-45-the-system-properties-no-longer-set-from-jnlp-tag-proper)

Answer (score 1):

I found a few problems I was using Eclipse to create the jar file and it wasn't building the Manifest with some of the expected settings so I created a manifest.txt and manually build the jar file.
there was a JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF sub dirs

jar cvfm jnlp.jar manifest.txt *

then I signed it

jarsigner -verbose -keystore myKeystore.jks jnlp.jar mycert

I also exported the self signed certificate into the Clients cacert ( Not sure if that was needed )

And I put the url in my java exception.sites file and I copied the APPLICATION.JNLP to the Web server as Test.jnlp

I also had a problem when coping the jar to the web server adding to the confusion. Then the properties in the jnlp started working.